# Install eigen3.3.7 on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, package, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to build a program on MacOS and that program requires Eigen `version <= 3.3.7` but mine has 3.3.8 with `brew install eigen`
I went to Eigen website but 3.3.7 source is no longer available anymore.
Any workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Updates: thanks a lot but I am still very confused with how to proceed. Below is the information of the installation details and directory info.

The directory of the program source code that I want to build look like:

```
program 
   cmake
   Cmakelist.txt
   build
```

the program has the following instructions:

```
Create the build directory in the source tree root

mkdir build
Configure cmake, from the build directory, passing the Shogun source root as an argument. It is recommended to use any of CMake GUIs (e.g. replace cmake .. with ccmake ..), in particular, if you feel unsure about possible parameters and configurations. Note that all cmake options read as -DOPTION=VALUE.

cd build
cmake [options] ..
Compile

make
Install (prepend sudo if installing system-wide), and you are done.

make install
Sometimes you might need to clean up your build (e.g. in case of some major changes). First, try

make clean
```

Then I have downloaded eigen3.3.7, where the INSTALL file is as following. How should I proceed?

```
Method 1. Installing without using CMake
****************************************

You can use right away the headers in the Eigen/ subdirectory. In order
to install, just copy this Eigen/ subdirectory to your favorite location.
If you also want the unsupported features, copy the unsupported/
subdirectory too.
Method 2. Installing using CMake
********************************

Let's call this directory 'source_dir' (where this INSTALL file is).
Before starting, create another directory which we will call 'build_dir'.

Do:

  cd build_dir
  cmake source_dir
  make install
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install Eigen 3.3.7 by compiling the source code([available here](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/releases/3.3.7)).

Comment: Thanks! can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: I updated my question description with how dir tree

Comment: @Erin have you tried following those instructions you pasted? If you have a specific error feel free to ask me about it.

Comment: yes I have. I build Eigen3.3.7 successfully, but I don't know how to let it use eigen3.3.7 when building the program... when building the program with cmake, it is still using eigtn3.3.8, which causes issue because Cmakelist.txt has the restraint that version <= 3.3.7.

Comment: I looked more into it, is it essentially copying Eigen3Config.cmake to the top of ProgramConfig.cmake?

Comment: @Erin It's a bit unclear what you're doing but my interpretation is that you need to build 3.3.7 and add it to your path so that the dependency is available. I also suggest uninstalling 3.3.8 to avoid confusion.