# Python - Installation build wheel error when installing from local directory

Tags: python, github, pip, cython

I want to install a package from GitHub that uses Cython (https://github.com/mlysy/kalmantv).  I cloned the package locally, and after trying to install it with `pip install .`, I'm getting the following error:

```
DEPRECATION: A future pip version will change local packages to be built in-place without first copying to a temporary directory. We recommend you use --use-feature=in-tree-build to test your packages with this new behavior before it becomes the default.
   pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7555.
Processing /Users/me/Downloads/kalmantv
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/bin/python3.8 /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/g1/0pjsd_bs24jgccrd6g0lzfvc0000gn/T/tmpxmrdlgnk
       cwd: /Users/me/Downloads/kalmantv
  Complete output (6 lines):
  running egg_info
  writing kalmantv.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to kalmantv.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to kalmantv.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to kalmantv.egg-info/top_level.txt
  error: package directory 'eigen-3.3.7' does not exist
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///Users/me/Downloads/kalmantv. Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/bin/python3.8 /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/g1/0pjsd_bs24jgccrd6g0lzfvc0000gn/T/tmpxmrdlgnk Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/bin/python3.8 /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/g1/0pjsd_bs24jgccrd6g0lzfvc0000gn/T/tmpxmrdlgnk Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried adding `--use-feature=in-tree-build` from the deprecation warning but still got the error (without the initial warning).

I saw a number of suggestions such as using `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`, but nothing is doing the trick. I would guess that this has a simple fix but this stuff is a little over my head and I don't want to break anything else.

What do I need to do to safely correct this issue without causing other problems?

Answer (score 0):

The `setup.py` file has the following lines:

```
# path to eigen library
EIGEN_PATH = r"eigen-3.3.7"
```

Strangely, it seems to expect the Eigen header library to be present at that location. You can install the library with `brew install eigen`, or `sudo apt install libeigen3-dev`. Note that this may not install version 3.3.7 of the library, which the project expects. I don't know if using a newer version would cause any issues.

If you want to install version 3.3.7, you can build and install it from source with the following link by following [these instructions](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/b78b2ede5f6156c8898c152335176cbd47c34bdb/INSTALL):

https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/releases/3.3.7

Once that's done, change to the project directory, and create a symlink to the Eigen library:

If installed with brew: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/*/include/eigen3 eigen-3.3.7`

If installed with apt: `ln -s /usr/include/eigen3 eigen-3.3.7`

If installed from source: `/usr/local/include/eigen3 eigen-3.3.7`

Once the Eigen library has been installed and made available at `./eigen-3.3.7`, `pip install .` should work, but for good measures you should run the following command first:

```sh
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel; pip install -U cython
```

Refer to [Catalina C++: Using <cmath> headers yield error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377) if you run into an error like: `error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace`.

Comment: I got a bunch of errors after installing with brew.  I'm trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745768/install-eigen3-3-7-on-macos (source: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/releases/3.3.7) and getting the same errors, which seem like they could be version issues, but here's an example:  `In file included from eigen-3.3.7/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h:679:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:317:9: error: no member named 'signbit' in the global namespace`

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah That seems to be a separate issue from what this question is about. This question is about why `pip install .` is giving you `error: package directory 'eigen-3.3.7' does not exist`, which has been fully answered. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628377 for a solution, or ask another question if your new issue is notably distinct from the one I just linked (and other questions like it on this site).